# Salesforce API: How to retrieve a Case using a partial Case Id

Tags: api, salesforce, soql

I'd like to retrieve a Case record from the Salesforce API. I only have the beginning of the Case Id [(don't ask why)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826843/salesforce-api-how-to-identify-a-case-from-an-email-reference-code-ref) so I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id LIKE 'whatever...%'
```

Unfortunately, this returns the following error:

```
SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id LIKE '500DABCD...%'
                          ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:27
invalid operator on id field'
How can we get this functionality from the API?
```

Why can't I use the LIKE operator on the Id field? Is there some other way I can do this?

Comment: Great question (+1), I'd like to find a way to do this without having to add a custom field though, so it can work cross orgs. My thought is maybe this is possible via SOSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a workaround: I've added a custom field to the Case entity that mirrors the Id field. I've found that (unlike the original Id field) I can query this field with the LIKE operator.

The field is of type "Formula (Text)" and I've set the formula to simply be "Id".

Comment: That'll work, although you should take into account there all the significant numbers in an id are at the end, the first three '500', just indicates the object type.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. The 500% was just for the sake of example. I'll fix the example to make it clearer.

I was actually going to use a more significant part of the Id that I was going to extract from a Case's reference ID parsed from email. Won't need to do that any more luckily. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826843/salesforce-api-how-to-identify-a-case-from-an-email-reference-code-ref